# rosgraph unable to get node information in Fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-comm, rosgraph, ros-fuerte, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Fuerte, `rosgraph`, `rxgraph` and `roswtf` do not work correctly for me. This error can be reproduced by running the following commands:

```
roscore
rosrun roscpp_tutorials talker
rosrun roscpp_tutorials listener
```

The nodes are definitely connected, as I can see the output from both the nodes. Additionally `rostopic hz` and `rostopic echo` can successfully subscribe to these messages. `rosgraph` is unable to determine the node connectivity, and gives the following output:

```
Nodes:
  /listener :
    Inbound:
    Outbound:
  /talker :
    Inbound:
    Outbound:
  /rosout :
    Inbound:
    Outbound:
Services:
  /talker/set_logger_level
  /listener/set_logger_level
  /rosout/get_loggers
  /talker/get_loggers
  /rosout/set_logger_level
  /listener/get_loggers
```

Similarly, `rxgraph` does not show this connectivity either, and the output can be seen in this [screenshot](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13356497769894451.gif). Note that the information for the listener node in the `rxgraph` sidebar seems correct. The sidebar information for the talker node can be seen in [screenshot-talker](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13356499785517484.gif).

`roswtf` seems to alternate randomly between:

```
Found 1 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/talker] raised an error:
```

and

```
Found 4 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/talker] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/listener] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/rosout] raised an error: 
ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /talker->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /listener->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /talker->/listener (/chatter)
```

I suspect the error to be somewhere in the rosgraph API. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Piyush

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32892/rosgraph-unable-to-get-node-information-in-fuerte/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2012-04-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem was attributed to 2 separate bugs in the rosgraph python scripts, that have been reported in 2 separate tickets ([ticket 3946](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3946) and [ticket 3947](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3947)). Patches to fix the problem are included in both tickets.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1